# Nvidia display tearing with System76 drivers

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

```
Laptop: Sytem76 Bonobo 15, 2024
PopOS 22.04
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4080
x11 (not Wayland)
```

After unpacking the laptop, I slotted in the NVMe stick that was running PopOS 22.04 on a Dell XPS 9710 laptop. It booted straight away, though the external display wasn't available, so I suppose it was using the built-in/Intel GPU. After runnnig the `apt` driver update, the Nvidia GPU became available, but had terrible graphic tearing issues where the most active parts of the display would jump and refresh constantly. I logged a call with System76, which advised me the following:

> It looks like the problem is that you installed the Nvidia driver for Ubuntu, trying to set it up with Prime. Although you are correct that this is an Optimus laptop that would normally use Prime, we have found that using our packaging results in a better experience.

```
# add the system76 PPA
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:system76-dev/stable
sudo apt update
# remove the current Nvidia packages
sudo apt purge ~nnvidia
# make sure we are getting the most recent release
sudo apt update
# make sure apt and dpkg were not interrupted
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt install -f  
# remove supporting libraries as well
sudo apt autoremove --purge
# install the nvidia driver
sudo apt install system76-driver-nvidia
# reboot the system to start using the new driver
sudo reboot
```

I did follow the steps, but the problem remains the same, i.e., screen tearing when using Nvidia graphics, somehow stable in hybrid mode if low graphic activity, and no issue of the sort with internal graphics.

This is the output from `nvidia-smi`:

```
# nvidia-smi 
Sat Mar 16 21:02:48 2024       

| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.14              Driver Version: 550.54.14      CUDA Version: 12.4     |

| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |

|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4080 ...    Off |   00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   46C    P8              4W /  150W |       9MiB /  12282MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |

| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |

|    0   N/A  N/A      2619      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              4MiB |
```

It is to be noted that upon running `nvidia-settings` while on the Nvidia graphics, the following error occurs:

```
** (nvidia-settings:92652): WARNING **: 21:23:21.908: PRIME: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/prime-supported” (No such file or directory)
```

This is the output of `nvidia-settings`, looking for PRIME:
[image]

I'm not sure why `prime-supported` is missing, but when I try to install it, it reports the following:

```
# apt install nvidia-prime
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
pop-desktop : PreDepends: pop-de-gnome but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: libreoffice-ogltrans
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

# apt install pop-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
pop-desktop is already the newest version (2.0.0~1697231037~22.04~733a5e2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

# apt install pop-de-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
pop-de-gnome is already the newest version (2.0.0~1697231037~22.04~733a5e2).
pop-de-gnome set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

**EDIT 1**

```
# apt list --installed|grep -i system76
gnome-shell-extension-system76-power/jammy,jammy,now 2.0.6~1710179797~22.04~b484f01 all [installed,automatic]
linux-firmware/jammy,now 20240202.git36777504-0ubuntu1+system76~1707150982~22.04~57636e6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-system76/jammy,now 6.6.10.76060610.202401051437~1709085277~22.04~31d73d8 amd64 [installed]
system76-acpi-dkms/jammy,now 1.0.2~1707324865~22.04~19ad0c5 amd64 [installed]
system76-dkms/jammy,now 1.0.14~1707324875~22.04~da04fd6 amd64 [installed]
system76-driver-nvidia/jammy,jammy,now 20.04.87~1710180195~22.04~5d0680a all [installed]
system76-driver/jammy,jammy,now 20.04.87~1710180195~22.04~5d0680a all [installed]
system76-firmware-daemon/jammy,now 1.0.59~1709142062~22.04~5250a40 amd64 [installed,automatic]
system76-io-dkms/jammy,now 1.0.3~1707324885~22.04~3dd4c32 amd64 [installed]
system76-oled/jammy,now 0.1.5~1664307225~22.04~98f778d amd64 [installed,automatic]
system76-power/jammy,now 1.1.26~1710180257~22.04~d7f73b2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
system76-scheduler/jammy,now 2.0.0~1701988455~22.04~b8d6545 amd64 [installed,automatic]
system76-wallpapers/jammy,jammy,now 18.04.2~1611351210~22.04~52abc1e all [installed,automatic]

# apt list --installed|grep -i nvidia
libnvidia-cfg1-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-common-550/jammy,jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a all [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-egl-wayland1/jammy,now 1:1.1.13-2pop1~1707162632~22.04~c5241b5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-extra-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a i386 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-compute-utils-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-dkms-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-525/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-firmware-550-550.54.14/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-common-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/jammy,now 510.47.03-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
system76-driver-nvidia/jammy,jammy,now 20.04.87~1710180195~22.04~5d0680a all [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550/jammy,now 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: since system 76 has its own repository - why did you not ask them about with a ticket?

Comment: Well, I did, but after receiving the instuctions quoted above, they more or less vanished -- I get an email every Friday afternoon asking me a dumb question to which I reply within minutes, but they get off for the weekend till the folliwiig Friday. Don't know if it's only with me, but as much as I like their hardware, their custormer support is just not there.

Comment: Ran `nvidia-bug-report.sh` and sent the collected logs to Nvidia. Let's see what happens.